# DOS renaming files troubleshooting

Tags: dos, filenames

I am trying to batch rename several files that are named using the following scheme: `picture.scn_xxx.png`.

- The placeholder `xxx` a numerical value ranging from `00000001` to
  (possibly) `99999999`.
- I would like to remove `.scn` to just have `picturexxx.png`.

**I've tried the following in command:**

```
ren picture.scn_*.png image*.png
```

However, this does not give me the desired result, I get `image.scn_xxx.png` instead. The `.scn` isn't removed( I was hoping to get `imagexxx.png`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %A in ('dir /b /a-d "picture.scn_*.png"') do ren "picture.scn_%B" "picture%B"
```

If used in a batch file then `%A` and `%B` must change to `%%A` and `%%B`